# How to rank by category - Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to create a Calculated Field that enables me to work out the current position (rank) of a participants of a race, lap by lap (around a track).

I've of course started with using the

```
=Rank()
```

command, but couldn't find a way to filter  out the other laps in order to work out a specific participants current rank in a given lap.

Here is some example data I quickly put together to use:
https://pastebin.com/xtn8JmWF

The result (for Bernard in this example data) for example, would rank him as: 2(nd) 1(st) 2(nd) 3(rd) 3(rd)

Answer (score 0):

I think this could help you
https://community.tableau.com/thread/251269 :)